# Python - Quadratic Equation PLS respond

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

We have to make a program that solves a quadratic equation, I did that part but we also have to include a section where the user inputs what they think the correct answer is and if they are right the program should output something like "You are correct". If they are wrong however, it should output something like "You are wrong" and then underneath it should output the correct answers. This is what i have so far can someone please incorporate this part for me My code is below.

```
print "This program can be used to solve quadratic equations"

print "Below, please input values for a, b, and c" 

print "\n----------------------------\n"

import math


for i in range(39479):

    a = float(raw_input("Enter a value for a: "))
    b = float(raw_input("Enter a value for b: "))
    c = float(raw_input("Enter a value for c: "))

    if a==0:
        print "Please input a value greater than or less than 0 for a"
    else:
        break

print "\n----------------------------\n"


discriminant = (b**2)-(4*(a*c)) 

if discriminant < 0:

    print ("This equation has no real solution")

elif discriminant == 0:

    repeated_solution = (-b-math.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))/2*a
    print ("This equation has one, repeated solution: "), repeated_solution

else:

    root_1 = (-b+math.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a)
    root_2 = (-b-math.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a)
    print "This equation has two solutions:", root_1, " and/or", root_2
```

Comment: so why can you not do this part of the code? It looks easier compared to the stuff you have done so far.

Comment: Idk why whenver i try to incorporate it, it doesn't work there's always an error statement. PLEASE just help me

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you are having an issue dealing with comparison part.  So you can add a realy basic validation, something look like that:
`d = float(raw_input("what is your answer: ")) 
if d*d=root_1*root_1 |   d*d=repeated_solution*repeated_solution:
    print('correct') 
else:
    print('false')`
Mathematically you compare the square of the answer with results the both cases lead to the same mechanic. to avoid issues of negative format. 
And delete the part when you print the results...

Answer (score 0):

```
print "This program can be used to solve quadratic equations"

print "Below, please input values for a, b, and c" 

print "\n----------------------------\n"

import math


for i in range(39479):

    a = float(raw_input("Enter a value for a: "))
    b = float(raw_input("Enter a value for b: "))
    c = float(raw_input("Enter a value for c: "))

    if a==0:
        print "Please input a value greater than or less than 0 for a"
    else:
        break

print "\n----------------------------\n"


discriminant = (b**2)-(4*(a*c)) 

if discriminant < 0:

    print ("This equation has no real solution")

elif discriminant == 0:

    repeated_solution = format((-b-math.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))/2*a,'.3f')
    guess=format(float(raw_input("This equation has one, repeated solution, Make a guess:")),'.3f')
    if guess==repeated_solution:
        print "You are correct.WOW!"
        print ("This equation has one, repeated solution: "), repeated_solution        
    else:
        print "Wrong Answer"
else:
    root_1 = format((-b+math.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a),'.3f')
    root_2 = format((-b-math.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a),'.3f')
    guess1=format(float(raw_input("This equation has two solutions, Make a guess for solution1:")),'.3f')
    guess2=format(float(raw_input("This equation has two solutions, Make a guess for solution2:")),'.3f')
    if set([root_1,root_2]).issubset( [guess1,guess2]):
        print "You are correct.WOW!"
        print "This equation has two solutions:", root_1, " and/or", root_2
    else:
        print "Wrong Answer"
```

Comment: Uhm, when i tried this code it says error : TypeError: Type floatdoesn't define __format__ on line 40

Comment: tested in python 2.7.9..what version u using?

Comment: It's like this school website thingy called CodeHS the link to it is: https://codehs.com/

Comment: Uhm it says like 2.7

Comment: Have you tried copying entire script and inserting it into an empty doc and run it?.

Comment: Yes, i tried the same code on replit and it works i dont know why it doesn't work on codehs???

Comment: One more question please, what does 'format' do and what does the .3f do at the end of the quadratic funtion

Comment: round value to 3 decimal places..say you have a result as  2.13564688484 it round it to 3 d.p.